# Getting Value from GridView Input Control using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using `Asp.Net Grid View Control` having `Template Field` Columns. Which have `Asp.Net Literal,TextBox and CheckBox` Controls. I want to add each row `Received Amount` value when checkbox is Checked in each row. Below is my GridView.

[image]

I have accessed the `Received Amount` columns by `JavaScript`, but it gives me the whole Textbox in `Alert`
[image]

I want to get Value of that Textbox having `Id=txtFeeRecAmount`, not whole Control..
Below is my `Script`..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function AddAmount(lnk) {
            var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
            var rowIndex = row.rowIndex;
            alert(rowIndex);
            var amount = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
            alert(amount);
        }
</script>
```

Any Help, I want to get Value of `Received Amount` Column, when the `CheckBox` is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, there can be multiple textboxes. there you need to get the current value by
using jquery, this should work;

```
 var amount = $(row.cells[2]).find('input').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged this question with jQuery I assume you are using it:

> I want to get Value of that Textbox having Id=txtFeeRecAmount

```
$("#txtFreeRecAmount").val();
```

Comment: its give me `undefined`

Comment: @ShahidIqbal, checkout my answer

Comment: There's a piece of the puzzle missing if you are getting undefined. [Quick sample fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/vb64M/).